# Queue java implementation issues, why design like this?

Tags: java

hi all，I'm learning queue data structure using java, but I've seen an abstract class defines an enumeration, enumeration defined here why should there even do good, or do what is so designed thanks

```
package com.jwetherell.algorithms.data_structures;

import java.util.Arrays;


/**
 * Queue. A queue is a particular kind of abstract data type or collection in
 * which the entities in the collection are kept in order and the principal (or
 * only) operations on the collection are the addition of entities to the rear
 * terminal position and removal of entities from the front terminal position.
 * This makes the queue a First-In-First-Out (FIFO) data structure. In a FIFO
 * data structure, the first element added to the queue will be the first one to
 * be removed.
 * 
 * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)
 * 
 * @author Justin Wetherell <phishman3579@gmail.com>
 */

public abstract class Queue<T> {

    public enum QueueType {
        LinkedQueue, ArrayQueue
    };

    /**
     * Enqueue the value in the queue.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            to enqueue.
     */
    public abstract void enqueue(T value);

    /**
     * Dequeue the head of the queue.
     * 
     * @return value that was dequeued.
     */
    public abstract T dequeue();

    /**
     * Does the queue contain the value. Warning this is an O(n) operation.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            to locate in the queue.
     * @return True if queue contains value.
     */
    public abstract boolean contains(T value);

    /**
     * Number of items in the queue.
     * 
     * @return number of items.
     */
    public abstract int size();

    /**
     * Create queue from QueueType.
     * 
     * @param type
     *            of queue to create.
     * @return Queue that was created.
     */
    public static <T> Queue<T> createQueue(QueueType type) {
        switch (type) {
            case ArrayQueue:
                return new ArrayQueue<T>();
            default:
                return new LinkedQueue<T>();
        }
    }
```

I'm sorry I did not make it clear before the problem, which is the source code

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Can you please clean up your question? I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Without more context it's impossible to say why this is implemented like this in the class you're looking at, and if this is a good solution or not.

Comment: The enumeration is used at the bottom in that static `createQueue`, and does exactly what it looks like its doing; its merely a way to create one subtype of Queue versus another, which in this case is either an `ArrayQueue`, or `LinkedQueue`. I'm sure there's other ways of doing this, but that's the way they chose. Can't tell you "why" beyond that.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the question is why we have the enums defined (`ArrayQueue` and `LinkedQueue`) for static factory method `createQueue` - and if this is a good design.

In my humble opinion, this is NOT a good design. I would not use a factory method for generic thing like a `Queue`. Users may have their own implementations of `Queue` and then you are stuck with this factory method that will not work with new implementations. Instead, just instantiate implementation you need at the place you need.

I would have factory for queues only if this is a business rule of the application - ie if the queue type is something configurable; but even then - i would never implement it in the abstract `Queue` class.